# Reversing a DateTime list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I've generated a list of timestamps using the following code:

```
    no_of_readings = int(math.ceil(no_of_seconds/measurement_interval))
    timestamps = [time_intervals[0]["timestamp"] - timedelta(seconds=x * measurement_interval)
                       for x in range(1, int(math.ceil(no_of_readings)))
                 ]
    timestamps.reverse()
```

But when I try to reverse the timestamps list, It returns **none.** 
What should I do to resolve this?

I believe that problem lies because elements are in form of `dataetime.datetime(2018,02,16,0,0,1)` . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "when I try to reverse the timestamps list, It returns none" — where is that code?

Comment: If something is filled and you reverse it and it is `None`- it might be an iterator that was consumed by displaying the contents once and then reversing it wont get you any results - other then that ... show us your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example

```
timestamps.reverse()
print timestamps
print timestamps.reverse()
```

The second print shows what reverse() returns

reverse() is supposed to return None, so I would guess you are seeing the correct behaviour

```
    >>> z=[x for x in range (1,37)]
    >>> z
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
    >>> z.reverse()
    >>> z
    [36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    >>> res=z.reverse()
    >>> res is None
True
```

Answer (score 2):

The `list.reverse` method reverses the list *in place*, but doesn't actually return the list. So after executing the code you showed, `timestamps` will contain the reverse list, even though `timestamps.reverse()` returned `None`.